# Multimaps.index() but producing a NavigableMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I need what is effectively an `ImmutableNavigableListMultimap<Integer, HasOffset>` where `HasOffset` looks like:

```
interface HasOffset {
   public int getOffset();
}
```

But there is no `ImmutableNavigableListMultimap`: what I want is an immutable [`NavigableMap<Integer, List<HasOffset>>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) that I create from a `List<HasOffset>` where I index each `HasOffset` by its offset. For example, if I had these objects:

```
115 Elm St. John Smith
115 Elm St. Jane Smith
108 Elm St. Thomas Little
101 Elm St. Bill Jones
115 Elm St. Buster Smith
112 Elm St. Mary Kay
101 Elm St. Judy Jones
```

then what I want is a Map that looks like

```
101 -> [Bill Jones, Judy Jones]
108 -> [Thomas Little]
112 -> [Mary Kay]
115 -> [John Smith, Jane Smith, Buster Smith]
```

where I can use a key and find the nearest values below or above that key.

Can Guava help or am I stuck doing it myself? I like [`Multimaps.index()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) but I don't think it can help me this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava is still a Java 5 library so you aren't going to find anything implementing `Navigable*` in it.

If you really wanted, you could kinda sorta fake this by first sorting the input to `Multimaps.index()` and then making use of the `ImmutableListMultimap`'s `keySet().asList()` view and doing a binary search for a key and making use of the index it returns. But that's not the same obviously.

Another option perhaps would be to use `Multimaps.index()` to take out the tedium of creating the map and then copy its `asMap()` view in to a `TreeMap<Integer, Collection<HasOffset>>`. Obviously there's some extra work going on there compared to just doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `TreeMultimap`, which has a `keySet()` method returning a `SortedSet`.

Then the largest key less than a given key is `multimap.keySet().headSet(key).last()`, while the smallest key greater than or equal to a given key is `multimap.keySet().tailSet(key).first()`. You could determine which of those two key is closer to the input key and retrieve its values from the multimap.

You'll have to handle the cases in which the input key is smallest than all multimap keys or larger than all of them. When the head set or tail set is empty, the `last()` and `first()` methods throw a `NoSuchElementException`.